# How to config nginx with same certification and same domain to proxy different applications

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have two applications,one of them I use ssl setting to proxy in nginx .
More specific,I want something like this
https://example.com:9099 and https://example.com:9090 in one machine using the same certification .

my config:

```
    server {
        listen       9090 ;
        server_name  example.com;
        #ssl_certificate      1_www.lw.example.com_bundle.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key  2_www.lw.example.com.key;
        #ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        #ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
        #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        #charset koi8-r;
        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        location / {
           root   /;
            index  /;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;
            proxy_buffers   32 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9095;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

       
    }
upstream  www{
     random two;
     server 127.0.0.1:9092;
     server 127.0.0.1:9093;
}
    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
    
        ssl_certificate      1_www.lw.example.com_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  2_www.lw.example.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;
            proxy_buffers   32 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
            proxy_pass http://www/;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
        listen       9099 ssl;
        server_name  example.com;
    }
```

In this config,I can get http://example.com:9090 and https://example.com:9099
But I want http://example.com:9090 to https://example.com:9090 too. Or I have to get another certification to solve this problem?

Comment: Use the same SSL configuration for the first `server` block and change `listen 9090;` to `listen 9090 ssl;`. To redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS you can use `error_page 497 =301 https://$host:9090$request_uri;` directive (see the description [here](https://chrisguitarguy.com/2019/08/20/redirecting-http-requests-on-an-https-listener-in-nginx-status-code-497/)).

Comment: It works , thank you